# Determining changes in subrepositories on remote server without commit in main repository

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I want to use hierarchical structure with mercurial repositories.

**Structure**

```
_Main  
Main/sub1  
Main/sub2_
```

**.hgsub**

```
sub1=sub1  
sub2=sub2  
[subpaths]  
somepath/Main/sub1=somepath/sub1  
somepath/Main/sub1=somepath/sub2
```

Then my colleagues will modify only ***sub1*** repository, they will not have ***Main*** repository.
How can I determine changes in sub1 than have been done by my colleagues.
**hg pull** does not see these changes if they are not commited at ***Main*** repository.

Or maybe It is incorrect structure and I must give to my colleagues ***Main*** repository containing data of ***sub1***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically pull and update each sub-repository to get their changes.  For example:

```
> hg pull -u -R sub1
> hg pull -u -R sub2
```

This will then change your `.hgsubstate` file to indicate that `Main` should use the latest version of each sub-repository.  You'll need to commit this change after doing the pull.

If you've made any changes to the sub-repositories yourself, you'll need to merge (or rebase) and commit those changes as normal before committing your `Main` repository.

Comment: Thank for the answer. As I think, It must be done manually.  I have clarified a purpose of my main subrepo and it is not a problem now.